# Hibernate updates only those fields that actually has been modified (by setter method)

Tags: hibernate

This is what I need:

1. Entity object (possibly through a proxy) keeps track of what setter methods have been called on the entity.
2. When Hibernate updates the object, the actual SQL UPDATE contains only those fields that actually has been modified.

Is this possible with Hibernate and how?

Comment: In the meantime, I have found a possible solution http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

Comment: this is the default behviour of hibernate, it won;t update a field that has not been updated ... how could it ?